# Does Google Sheets Regex engine support lookbehind?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, re2

I was under the impression that Sheets supports re2, which does not support *lookaround*.

Consider he following Sheet's example script.
Regex expected to match the word **dog** either by itself or if preceded by the word **cat**.

```
function testRegex(){
  
  var rg = /(?<=(cat|\b))dog/;
  var s = "catdog";
  
  Logger.log("%s: %s",s,rg.test(s));
  
  s = "sdog";
  Logger.log("%s: %s",s,rg.test(s));
  
  s = "dog";
  Logger.log("%s: %s",s,rg.test(s));
  
}
```

The results are perfect:
[image: The results are perfect:]

So question is supported or not?

Comment: Well, it seems working.

Comment: @Toto It looks like it does. My question is whether my understandings were wrong, or is it something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using JavaScript in your Google Apps script. GAS now uses the modern JavaScript engine that supports lookbehinds, named capturing groups, `s` modifier. So, your pattern works well.

If you use a lookbehind pattern in a `REGEXEXTRACT` or `REGEXREPLACE` formula, it will fail as those `REGEX~` functions use RE2 regex library. You can't use a lookbehind there.